# Python 3 Operator Overloading

Tags: class, python-3.x, operator-overloading

I'm trying to define the operator type **add** when it comes to my class Point. Point is exactly what it seems, (x, y). I can't seem to get the operator to work though because the code keeps printing the <**main**.Point...>. I'm pretty new to this stuff, so can someone explain what I am doing wrong? Thanks. Here is my code:

```
class Point:
def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
def __add__(self, other):
    return Point(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)
p1 = Point(3,4)
p2 = Point(5,6)
p3 = p1 + p2
print(p3)
```

Comment: _"the code keeps printing the `<main.Point...>`"_. Sounds normal to me. What do you expect it to print?

Answer (score 1):

Your add function is working as intended. It's your `print` that's the problem. You're getting an ugly result like `<__main__.Point object at 0x027FA5B0>` because you haven't told the class how you want it to display itself. Implement [`__str__`](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__repr__#object.__str__) or [`__repr__`](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__repr__#object.__repr__) so that it shows a nice string.

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __add__(self, other):
        return Point(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Point({}, {})".format(self.x, self.y)
p1 = Point(3,4)
p2 = Point(5,6)
p3 = p1 + p2
print(p3)
```

Result:

```
Point(8, 10)
```